# DB2 C# Date Conversion

Tags: c#, date

I am migrating about 60 tables of data from DB2 to SQL server.
The problem I have is with Date (I use that work lightly) fields in the DB2 tables.
The tables have approximately 15 years worth of data in them. Over the time there
have been dates stored in most tables in either Data type fields or in string (Char)
type fields. Some of these table contain in excess of 1 milllion records.

Add to this the dates have been stored in various formats

Here are a few.

```
23.06.2005
06.23.2005
2005.06.23
23.06.05
06.23.05

23/06/2005
06/23/2005
2005/06/23
23/06/05
06/23/05

23-06-2005
06-23-2005
2005-06-23
23-06-05
06-23-05
```

When the DB2 field is a Data Type field I have no problem.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(dsSourceData[j].ToString(), new CultureInfo("en-CA"));
```

I do however have a problem when the DB2 field is a String type.  The above conversion
fails.

Has anyone any idea how I may overcome this problem ?

I would appreciate and assistance offered

Kind regards

Iain

Comment: The examples I have shown above are in the formats I have in the tables.The DB2 type fields are either L (Date Type) or Chars. The Date type fields are not presenting a problem. It is the Char/String types that are giving me an issue. Using .Substring() is almost impossible

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to provide a working solution because you have two contradictory formats where the day and month is on interchanging positions: "23.06.05" and "06.23.05". So what does this date for example mean: `"07.08.09"`?

However, normally you use `DateTime.TryParseExact` with multiple format-string for this:

```
string[] formats={"dd.MM.yyyy", "yyyy.MM.dd", "dd.MM.yy"}; // to be continued
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-CA");
var validDates = dateStrings
    .Select(s => (valid:DateTime.TryParseExact(s, formats, culture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var dt),date:dt))
    .Where(x => x.valid)
    .Select(x => x.date)
    .ToArray();
```

Read: [Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: *"It's impossible to provide a working solution..."* - it may be possible to provide a solution, or a partial solution, if there is further information available to determine which date style is in use. For example, a particular user or team may be found (on close analysis) to have a consistent style, or different tables may have different conventions (he mentions 60 tables), or different conventions may be found to apply during different eras, or there may be other data available in the system from which inferences can be drawn. (1/2)

Comment: Also, a small amount of error may also be irrelevant for statistics, or can be corrected sufficiently by a statistical analysis of the relative frequency of unambiguous dates, and the weighting of ambiguous dates accordingly. For example, only day numbers up to 12 are ambiguous with months, so the relative prevalence of each date format could be inferred from the existence of unambiguous dates involving day numbers 13-31. The days of the week on which each possible date falls could also be analysed. With 15 years of data, it's highly likely to be a statistical exercise anyway. (2/2)

Comment: Many thanks for your response Tim. It has given me much to think about and some good pointers. I am looking up the field data types andd trying to handle it that way. I can treat the Date And Char types differently.

Comment: I have relented and created a program on teh AS400 to modiy the data formats in all of the files to a single format. Can't be botheresd with all of the fannying about

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Much appreciated